# Наполнить переменную типа rowtype в oracle из php

Tags: php, oracle

Всем привет) в общем ситуация) в oracle есть переменная типа rowtype, как мне ее наполнить данными полученными с формы, с помощью PHP. Сейчас я делаю так:

```
insert into название_пакета_процедур.переменная_типа_rowtype (поле_1,поле_2) values (значение_1, значение_2)
```

Но данный метод не работает. пишет данная таблица или представление не заданы.

Пробовал через `SELCECT`

```
select значение_1, значение_2 into название_пакета_процедур.переменная_типа_rowtype.поле_1,название_пакета_процедур.переменная_типа_rowtype.поле_2 from dual
```

то же не работает не может найти данные переменные.

Может есть какие либо ещё варианты.

Comment: Да были пробовал через select into не получилось

Comment: Проблема со стороны Oracle (не можете написать запрос) или со стороны PHP (не можете передать данные в запрос)? Вопрос будет яснее если добавить в него пример кода и рассказать что не получилось.

Comment: Окей, сейчас сделаю

Comment: Проблема в том, что я не могу найти как это примерно сделать, пробовал через insert into не получается

Comment: @Dmitry [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ОК, не буду.

Comment: @Dmitry Большое спасибо!

Comment: @АлексейСемянников `insert into` - это только для вставки в таблицу. Второй запрос - ОЧЕНЬ сильно зависит то того, как именно у вас там описаны значения. Правильнее всего через параметры делать (`select :PARAM1, :PARAM2, into ...`).

Comment: Ой, ошибся с утра. `select ... into ...` - это же только для PL/SQL. Надо в `begin ... end;` завернуть. Посмотрите, как в PHP выполнить анонимный PL/SQL блок.